# Mathematical definition of perfect substitutes

Tags: microeconomics, utility, preferences

If $X$ and $Y$ are perfect substitutes such that a unit of $X$ can be replaced by $n$ units of $Y$, how do we get the mathematical equation from it? I know the equation is of the form $ax+by$ (and $U = b(nx+y)$ for this case), but how do we arrive at that?

If the utility function is $U(x,y)$, can we say that any function $U$ satisfying $U(x+1,y) = U(x,y+n)$ will describe this relation between $X$ and $Y$? (Assume that $U$ is increasing to ensure the non-satiation property.)

Comment: Is this a `history-of-economic-thought` question, are you asking who first defined perfect substitutes and how?

Comment: @Giskard Not really.

Answer (score 4):

1. > If $X$ and $Y$ are perfect substitutes such that a unit of $X$ can be replaced by $n$ units of $Y$ [...] I know [...] $U=b(nx+y)$ for this case

This is a possible representation but not the only one. E.g., $\tilde{U}=(nx+y)^2$ represents the same preferences.

2. > how do we arrive at that?

Perfect substitutes (with a substitution ratio of $1:n$) defines a preference relation $\succeq$ over the baskets of goods. A possible definition of the perfect substitutes preference relation over $\mathbb{R}^2$ is that the relation fulfills the following two properties:

i) $(x_1,y_1) \sim (x_2,y_2) \text{ iff } nx_1 + y_1 = nx_2 + y_2$ 
ii) monotonicity

Though ii) is generally implied, it is not strictly necessary - e.g., two bads can also be perfect subtitutes.

As I already pointed it out above, there are many utility functions that *represent* this preference.

3. > can we say that any function $U$ satisfying $U(x+1,y) = U(x,y+n)$ will describe this relation [...]?

If you restrict yourself to integer numbers, sure. A possible reformulation of
$$(x_1,y_1) \sim (x_2,y_2) \text{ iff } nx_1 + y_1 = nx_2 + y_2$$
is
$$(x_1,y_1) \sim (x_2,y_2) \text{ iff } n(x_1-x_2) = y_2-y_1$$
which is indeed fulfilled by the equation above.

Comment: Restrict to integers, as in, $n$ being an integer or $\text{domain}(U) = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Not just $U=(nx+y)^2$ but *probably* every $g(nx+y)$ where $g$ is non-decreasing considering the definition you gave.

Comment: Indeed they are.

Comment: Thanks. And what about the "restrict to integers"?

Comment: I may have misunderstood you there. I thought you meant for $x,y,n$ all to be integers, in which case your definition only covers $U$'s domain if it is $\mathbb{Z}^2$. If $x,y,n$ can have any real value then your definition seems general enough.

Comment: Okay. If that is general enough, then it actually leads to a problem. Because then it *should* be equivalent to the PDE I wrote [in the other question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/50349/marginal-utility-meaning-and-properties). But this recurrence and that PDE are not *generally* equivalent.

Comment: What is a 'PDE'? In your other question only 3. comes close to this, but it only covers the line $(t,nt)$ in the space of good baskets, not the entire space, and as such, it is not at all equivalent to your definition here.

Comment: PDE is partial differential equation. It's a commonly used acronym (in English textbooks). If two elements are perfect substitutes w/ ratio $1:n$, then we can say that $U(x+1,y) = U(x,y+n)$. In the [other thread](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/50354/33107), you say the same $X$ and $Y$ can be represented by $\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} = n \cdot \frac{\partial U}{\partial y}$. But this recurrence and this PDE are not equivalent in general. 

If two elements are perfect substitutes then they always satisfy the recurrence you said.

Comment: (Cont. of the previous comment) The PDE is equivalent to $g(nx+y) \implies U(x+1,y) = U(x,y+n)$. But the converse, that is, $U(x+1,y) = U(x,y+n) \implies \frac{\partial U}{\partial x} = n \cdot \frac{\partial U}{\partial y}$ probably does not hold in general.